# Не получается добавить SSL-сертификат в nginx

Tags: nginx, windows-10, ssl, openssl

Мне нужно использовать в nginx самоподписанный SSL-сертификат для localhost.
Для создания приватного ключа и сертификата использовал OpenSSL следующим образом:

```
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out private.key 2048
openssl rsa -in private.key -out private.key
openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -sha1 -key private.key -out certificate.cer -days 36500
```

В качестве common name при создании сертификата указал localhost. Ключ и сертификат переместил в папку D:\Applications\nginx-1.21.1\ssl_cert, сертификат установил в Доверенные Коренные центры сертификации.

Файл настроек nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes  1;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  localhost;

        ssl_certificate      D:\Applications\nginx-1.21.1\ssl_cert\certificate.cer;
        ssl_certificate_key  D:\Applications\nginx-1.21.1\ssl_cert\private.key;

        location / {
            root   "D:\Work Related\ui\build";
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
    }


}
```

При запуске nginx получаю следующую ошибку:

```
D:\Applications\nginx-1.21.1>nginx
nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate "D:\Applications
ginx-1.21.1\ssl_cert\certificate.cer": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:0200107B:system library:fopen:Unknown error:fopen('D:\Applications
ginx-1.21.1\ssl_cert\certificate.cer','r') error:2006D002:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:system lib)
```

Как её решить?

Comment: Бекслеши надо экранировать. `D:\\Appications\\nginx-....`

Comment: Да, после экранирования nginx запустился